# Usage of return in JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise, callback

I'm trying to understand promises better.
I'm making a async call to an API and then based on the response, I want to do some more operations, for this I'm using the below 2 approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
function getABValues(){
     getValueOfA() /*this returns aOutput*/
     .then(function (aOutput){
      getValueOfB() /*this returns bOutput*/
     })
     .then(function (bOutput){
      console.log(bOutput);
     })
    }
```

**Approach 2:**

```
function getABValues(){
     return getValueOfA() /*this returns aOutput*/
     .then(function (aOutput){
      return getValueOfB() /*this returns bOutput*/
     })
     .then(function (bOutput){
      console.log(bOutput);
     })
    }
```

Here are functions getValueOfA() and getValueOfB():

**getValueOfA()**

```
function getValueOfA(){
 return aOutput;
}
```

**getValueOfB():**

```
function getValueOfB(){
 return bOutut; 
}
```

If you notice, `getValueOfA()` and `getValueOfB()` are already returning values, do I still need to use return when calling `getValueOfA()` and `getValueOfB()` before using `then`.

Approach 1 doesn't use `return` while approach 2 uses `return`.

Thanks for clarifying

Comment: The code is not equivalent, since in approach 1, bOutput will be undefined since the previous step did not return getValueOfB() . It also only makes sense if `aOutput` is already a promise, since else getValueOfA() will not return something that you can chain `.then()` to. So the answer is: you always have to return within a `.then()` handler function if you want what you return to be available as the parameter of the next `.then()` chained to it.

Comment: if getValueOfA() returns a promise, then will it be an issue if I add another return when calling getValueOfA() as it is already returning?

Comment: For clarity, `aOutput` and `bOutput` would be better named `aPromise` and `bPromise`. If they were not thenable (most likely Promises), then `getValueOfA().then(...)` and `getValueOfB().then(...)` would throw.

Comment: No, each function can (and probably should) have its own return. This (generally) includes functions which are `.then()` callbacks.

Comment: My doubt is if they are returning promises, but again if I'm adding another return when calling them, like return getValueOfA() where getValueOfA() already has a return and it is returning a promise

Comment: Returns are vital. The only way for a .then() callback function to deliver a value (or to deliver a Promise that will eventually deliver a value) is for that callback to make a return. If it fails to return anything, then, as always, it will return `undefined`. Whatever is returned gets delivered to the next stage in the promise chain.

Comment: More accurately, whatever is returned gets delivered to the next `.then()` in the promise chain. If the next stage is a `.catch()`, it will see only errors, but will be transparent to successes.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing directly to do with promises.

`function getABValues()` in Approach 1 has no return statement. It will return `undefined`.

`function getABValues()` in Approach 2 has a return statement. It will return the result of evaluating `getValueOfA().then(something).then(something)` which will be a promise.

So Approach 2 will allow you to:

```
getABValues().then(do_something_with_those_values);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const API = {
  ids: 0,
  get: function( value ) {
    return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ) {
      const timer = Math.random( Math.random() * 2 );
      setTimeout(function() {
        API.ids += 1;
        resolve([{ "id": API.ids, "value": value }]);
      }, timer );
    });
  }
};
// The mock API will give us a promise object.
// We want to return that promise object.
// So we can use the value of the promise in .then()
const getValueOfA = function() {
  return API.get( 'value A' );
};
const getValueOfB = function() {
  return API.get( 'value B' );
};

// We want to chain both API to resolve in order.
const getABValues = function() {
  // If we do not return, we cannot use getABValues().then( ... )
  // Outside of this function.
  return getValueOfA()
    // If we did not return inside getValueOfA(), we would not have the API promise.
    // And then this line will throw an error
    // Since undefined does not have a method called .then()
    .then(function( resolvedValueOfPromiseA ) {
      // We can use resolvedValueOfPromiseA here, which will be the value:
      // [{"id":1,"value":"value A"}]
      console.log( 'inside getValueOfA().then( ... )' );
      console.log( JSON.stringify( resolvedValueOfPromiseA ));
      // Return getValueOfB() so we can use the resolvedValueOfPromiseB
      return getValueOfB();
      // We could also use
      //
      // return getValueOfB( resolvedValueOfPromiseA );
      //
      // If we change the getValueOfB() function to have a aprameter and use it.
      // Then we can use the value of resolvedValueOfPromiseA
      // Inside getValueOfB()
    })
    .then(function( resolvedValueOfPromiseB ) {
      console.log( 'inside getValueOfA().then( ... ).then( ... )' );
      console.log( JSON.stringify( resolvedValueOfPromiseB ));
      return resolvedValueOfPromiseB;
    });
};
// Use the function on the outside.
// We can call .then() since getABValues() returns the entire promise chain.
getABValues()
  .then(function( resolvedValueOfPromiseBReturnedByThen ) {
    console.log( 'inside getABValues().then( ... )' );
    console.log( JSON.stringify( resolvedValueOfPromiseBReturnedByThen ));
  });
// Notice how here we only have the result of getValueOfB()
// Since we did not do anything with resolvedValueOfPromiseA in the .then() function
// THat ahd access to resolvedValueOfPromiseA
```

Comment: Perfect. Clear now. This is what I'm looking for